# Erro no meu programa C

Tags: c, stack, fila

Preciso criar um programa em C, que remova (ou copie) os valores de uma fila, usando as regras de saída de uma pilha e os adicione em uma nova estrutura.

Montei conforme abaixo mas ocorre dois erros:

> "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'
> File not found: ctr0_c.c"
>
> "error:Id returned 1 exit status
> File not found: collect2.exe"

Alguém pode me ajudar aonde estou errando? O que devo mudar?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

//Constantes
#define tamanho 5

//Fila
struct estrutura{
   int dados [tamanho];
   int ini;
   int fim;
};

//variaveis globais
struct estrutura fila;
struct estrutura pilha;
int op;

//prototipacao
void fila_entrar();
void fila_sair();
void fila_mostrar();
void menu_mostrar ();
void pilha_mostrar();
void pilha_mover();

//funcao principal
int mais(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    op=1;
    fila.ini=0;
    fila.fim=0;
    pilha.ini=0;
    pilha.fim=0;
    while(op!=0){
        system("cls");
        fila_mostrar();
        pilha_mostrar();
        menu_mostrar();
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch(op){
        case 1:
            fila_entrar();
            break;
        case 2:
            fila_sair();
            break;
        case 3:
            pilha_mover();
            break;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

//add elemento no final da fila
void fila_entrar(){
    if(fila.fim==tamanho){
        printf("\nA fila está cheia\n");
        system("Pause");
    }else{
        printf("\nDigite o valor a ser inserido: ");
        scanf("%d", &fila.dados[fila.fim]);
        fila.fim++;
    }
}

//retirar o primeiro elemento da fila
void fila_sair(){
    if(fila.ini==fila.fim){
        printf("\nA fila esta vazia, adicione algum valor\n");
        system("Pause");
    }else{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
            fila.dados[i]=fila.dados[i+1];
        }
        fila.dados[fila.fim]=0;
        fila.fim--;
    }
}

//mostra o conteudo da fila
void fila_mostrar(){
    int i;
    printf("[ ");
    for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
        printf(" %d", fila.dados[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n\n");
}

//mostra o menu de opções
void menu_mostrar(){
    printf("\nEscolha uma opção:\n");
    printf("1- Incluir na fila\n");
    printf("2- Excluir da fila\n");
    printf("3- Mover para a pilha\n");
    printf("0-Sair\n\n");
}

//mostrar conteudo da pilha
void pilha_mostrar(){
    int i;
    printf("[ ");
    for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
        printf(" %d", pilha.dados[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n\n");
}

//mover para a pilha
void pilha_mover(){
    if(fila.ini==fila.fim){
        printf("\nA fila esta vazia, adicione algum valor\n");
        system("Pause");
    }else{
        pilha.dados[pilha.fim]=fila.dados[fila.fim];
        pilha.fim++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16' File not found: ctr0_c.c"

Ou seja, você não definiu a função `main` em lugar nenhum. O que ocorre é que você digitou ela errado, colocou `mais()` ao invés de `main()`. Além disso, ou você terá que colocar a sua função `main` no final ou então declarar um protótipo dela no começo da mesma forma que você fez para as outras funções.

Comment: Muito obrigado !!!
Revisei e passou batido...

Será que consegue me dar mais uma ajuda ?
Porque a função de Mover para a  pilha não funciona ?

Comment: @Tejota Na função `pilha_mover`, me parece que você pega um elemento da fila sem removê-lo de lá. Além disso, nas funções `pilha_mover` e `fila_sair`, você parece tirar os elementos do fim da fila, e não no início.

Comment: @VictorStafusa: a funcao `main()` nao precisa de prototipo. Colocar a funcao `main()` no final tem apenas a funcionalidade de considerar a definicao de outras funcoes como prototipo.